# How to cite website with mdpi template using bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, pdftex, texmaker, mdpi

I'm trying to cite a website using pdflatex, better-bibtex, zotero and texmaker.
Citations of articles are working like charm, but I get an error with the citation of a websites:

```
Warning: Citation `xxx' on page y undefined on input line
```

The automatically create bibtex entry from zotero is the following:

```
@misc{ogredevelopmentteamOGREOpenSource2019,
  title = {{{OGRE}} - {{Open Source 3D Graphics Engine}}},
  language = {en-US},
  journal = {OGRE - Open Source 3D Graphics Engine},
  howpublished = {https://www.ogre3d.org/},
  author = {{Ogre Development Team}},
  year = {2019},
}
```

I'm loading my references like this:

```
\bibliography{./Bibliography/references}
```

And I'm using the following document class:

```
\documentclass[journal, article, submit, moreauthors, pdftex, atmosphere]{Definitions/mdpi}
```

In my text I'm citing the website like this:

```
\citep{ogredevelopmentteamOGREOpenSource2019}
```

And I'm building my whole document like this:

```
PdfLatex + Bibtex + PdfLatex (x2) + Show PDF
```

All other citations are working..

Comment: Please -- as usual here -- make your code snippets compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing. Do you have a link to your used class `mdpi`?

Comment: If I download the template from https://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex and modify `template.tex` to use BibTeX (i.e. remove the manual `thebibliography` *References, variant A* and uncomment *variant B*), add the example entry to a `.bib` file, cite `ogredevelopmentteamOGREOpenSource2019` and compile with LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX, I get the expected output. Delete the temporary files and try again. Double check the `.bib` file contains the entry and that it is the correct `.bib` file. What does the `blg` file say?

Answer (score 5):

The entry type for websites defined in `mdpi.bst` is `www`. Your example would look like this:

```
@www{ogredevelopmentteamOGREOpenSource2019,
    author = {{Ogre Development Team}}, 
    title = {{{OGRE}} - {{Open Source 3D Graphics Engine}}},
    url = {https://www.ogre3d.org/},
    urldate = {xx.xx.2019},
}
```

(`urldate` is the date on which the website was accessed)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, If you do not know how to generate website citation, use any online generator citation (for example, http://www.citationmachine.net).
Secondly, create your `your_ref.bib` file (if you do not know, you can use mendely to export `your_ref.bib` file).
Thirdly, replace ( `\bibliography{your_ref.bib}` instead of `\bibliography{your_external_BibTeX_file}`

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: I faced this error and fixed it by following these steps