# Cannot generate references while using the MDPI journal template

Tags: bibtex, templates, winedt

I am trying to compile my MDPI Journal using the [LaTeX template found here](https://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex).

I am trying to use the variant A: external bibliography style as follows:

```
%=====================================
% References, variant A: external bibliography
%=====================================
\externalbibliography{yes}
\bibliography{MDPI_1_Refs}

%=====================================
% References, variant B: internal bibliography
%=====================================
%\begin{thebibliography}{999}
%% Reference 1
```

I have created my .bib file called MDPI_1_Refs.bib:

```
@article{Harries,
   author = {Harries, Keith},
   title = {Property Crimes and Violence in United States: An Analysis of the Influence of Population Density},
   journal = {Int J Criminal Justice Sci},
   volume = {1},
   year = {2007},
   type = {Journal Article}
}

@article{Battin,
   author = {Battin, Joshua R. and Crowl, Justin N.},
   title = {Urban sprawl, population density, and crime: an examination of contemporary migration trends and crime in suburban and rural neighborhoods},
   journal = {Crime Prevention and Community Safety},
   volume = {19},
   number = {2},
   pages = {136-150},
   ISSN = {1743-4629},
   DOI = {10.1057/s41300-017-0020-9},
   url = {https://doi.org/10.1057/s41300-017-0020-9},
   year = {2017},
   type = {Journal Article}
}
```

I am using WinEdt with PDFLaTeXify

I have read a few forum posts like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510222/how-should-i-compile-bibliography-using-mdpi-template) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479589/how-to-cite-website-with-mdpi-template-using-bibtex), but I still have not been able to generate the references.  Can you assist me in telling me how to go about correctly generating the references for this journal template using an external `.bib` file?

When I look at the `'blg` file I get this:

```
[0] Config.pm:311> INFO - This is Biber 2.16
[0] Config.pm:314> INFO - Logfile is 'Paper_MDPI_PlasticDatabase1.blg'
[279] biber-MSWIN64:340> INFO - === 
[1060] Utils.pm:411> ERROR - Cannot find 'Paper_PlasticDatabase1.bcf'!
[1061] Biber.pm:132> INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

This is a screen shot of my `PDFLaTeX` Execution Modes window in WinEdt:

[image]

Comment: Since the template uses a BibTeX-based bibliography (if you are not writing a manual `thebibliography`) with `natbib`, it is incompatible with Biber, so I removed that tag.

Comment: Is there a chance you could run pdfLaTeX and BibTeX manually on that file instead of going via `PDFLaTeXify`? `PDFLaTeXify` sometimes hides the real source of the error and generally makes debugging much harder. If you run pdfLaTeX and BibTeX directly, they should tell you about errors in their `.log` and `.blg` files. Check those carefully.

Comment: you have not provided an example document, but the document needs to have `\cite{Battin}` or `\cite{Harries}` then you need to run pdflatex then bibtex then pdflatex again to generate the document including the bibliography.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I do have the `\cite{Battin}` and `\cite{Harries}` in my document.

Comment: @moewe, I ran `PDFLaTeX` and `BibTeX` separately in WinEdt.  It appears that  `BibTeX` used `Biber`.  Do I have to do something differently here then for `BibTeX`?

Comment: On this document you need to run BibTeX, not Biber. So you need to tell your editor to run BibTeX.

Comment: That document may do but the example code that you post does not help anyone solve your problem if it is not an example of the problem. If you post unusable fragments that have no chance of making a bibliography as there are no `\cite` then it is very hard to tell you what error in an unseen document is stopping the bibliography.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you downloaded the template and put it in a new directory. It should have a file `template.tex` and a `Definitions`  subdirectory.

Instead of the template, I made a new file `TestingMDPI.tex`. Put it in the same directory, along with your  `MDPI_1_Refs.bib` file.

`TestingMDPI.tex` has only the **Introduccion** with the added phrase  `Citing two journal papers \cite{Harries,Battin}.`

Now compile `TestingMDPI` with `pdflatex`. If the processing chain has `biber` incorporated, do not worry now. After several builds you should  get as output

[image: a]

Note that there is not a section **References** and also says `Citing two journal papers [?,?]`.

Now run `bibtex TestingMDPI`. (no extension) I do not use WinEdt, so I can not help there. You can always run it from a command window. (`bibtex` is an `.exe` file in the path)

In the console you should get

```
Process started: bibtex.exe "TestingMDPI"

bibtex: security risk: running with elevated privileges
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 21.3)
The top-level auxiliary file: TestingMDPI.aux
The style file: Definitions/mdpi.bst
Database file #1: MDPI_1_Refs.bib
Process exited normally
```

Run `pdflatex` again. This time the references section will appear with the two papers (unnumbered), and still
`Citing two journal papers [?,?]`

[image: b]

Do it again. Now you should have the final version with:

`Citing two journal papers [1,2]`

[image: c]

(Sometimes more runs are needed until everything is stable)

If all goes well, the next step would be to configure the WinEdt processing chain, replacing `biber` with `bibtex`, so that the entire process runs on its own.

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex
%=================================================================
\documentclass[journal,article,submit,moreauthors,pdftex]{Definitions/mdpi} 
%=================================================================
% MDPI internal commands
\firstpage{1} 
\makeatletter 
\setcounter{page}{\@firstpage} 
\makeatother
\pubvolume{1}
\issuenum{1}
\articlenumber{0}
%\doinum{}
\pubyear{2021}
\copyrightyear{2020}
%\externaleditor{Academic Editor: Firstname Lastname} % For journal Automation, please change Academic Editor to "Communicated by"
\datereceived{} 
\dateaccepted{} 
\datepublished{} 
\hreflink{https://doi.org/} % If needed use \linebreak
%------------------------------------------------------------------

% Full title of the paper (Capitalized)
\Title{Title}

% MDPI internal command: Title for citation in the left column
\TitleCitation{Title}

% Author Orchid ID: enter ID or remove command
\newcommand{\orcidauthorA}{0000-0000-0000-000X} % Add \orcidA{} behind the author's name

% Authors, for the paper (add full first names)
\Author{Firstname Lastname $^{1,\dagger,\ddagger}$\orcidA{}, Firstname Lastname $^{1,\ddagger}$ and Firstname Lastname $^{2,}$*}

% MDPI internal command: Authors, for metadata in PDF
\AuthorNames{Firstname Lastname, Firstname Lastname and Firstname Lastname}

% MDPI internal command: Authors, for citation in the left column
\AuthorCitation{Lastname, F.; Lastname, F.; Lastname, F.}
% If this is a Chicago style journal: Lastname, Firstname, Firstname Lastname, and Firstname Lastname.

% Affiliations / Addresses (Add [1] after \address if there is only one affiliation.)
\address{%
$^{1}$ \quad Affiliation 1; e-mail@e-mail.com\\
$^{2}$ \quad Affiliation 2; e-mail@e-mail.com}

% Contact information of the corresponding author
\corres{Correspondence: e-mail@e-mail.com; Tel.: (optional; include country code; if there are multiple corresponding authors, add author initials) +xx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx (F.L.)}

% Current address and/or shared authorship
\firstnote{Current address: Affiliation 3} 
\secondnote{These authors contributed equally to this work.}

% Abstract (Do not insert blank lines, i.e. \\) 
\abstract{A single paragraph of about 200 words maximum. For research articles, abstracts should give a pertinent overview of the work. We strongly encourage authors to use the following style of structured abstracts, but without headings: (1) Background: place the question addressed in a broad context and highlight the purpose of the study; (2) Methods: describe briefly the main methods or treatments applied; (3) Results: summarize the article's main findings; (4) Conclusion: indicate the main conclusions or interpretations. The abstract should be an objective representation of the article, it must not contain results which are not presented and substantiated in the main text and should not exaggerate the main conclusions.}

% Keywords
\keyword{keyword 1; keyword 2; keyword 3 (List three to ten pertinent keywords specific to the article; yet reasonably common within the subject discipline.)} 


\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setcounter{section}{-1} %% Remove this when starting to work on the template.
\section{How to Use this Template}

The template details the sections that can be used in a manuscript. Note that the order and names of article sections may differ from the requirements of the journal (e.g., the positioning of the Materials and Methods section). Please check the instructions on the authors' page of the journal to verify the correct order and names. For any questions, please contact the editorial office of the journal or support@mdpi.com. For LaTeX-related questions please contact latex@mdpi.com.

\section{Introduction}

The introduction should briefly place the study in a broad context and highlight why it is important. It should define the purpose of the work and its significance. The current state of the research field should be reviewed carefully and key publications cited. Please highlight controversial and diverging hypotheses when necessary. Finally, briefly mention the main aim of the work and highlight the principal conclusions. As far as possible, please keep the introduction comprehensible to scientists outside your particular field of research. 

Citing two journal papers \cite{Harries,Battin}. %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< needed

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{paracol}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\reftitle{References}


%=====================================
% References, variant A: external bibliography
%=====================================
\externalbibliography{yes}
\bibliography{MDPI_1_Refs.bib}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Added from [BibTex using LaTeX2e in WinEdt](http://www.u.arizona.edu/%7Eppoon/BibTeX%20in%20WinEdt.htm) NOT tested, might be old.

> Hit the following key combinations:
>
> ```
> CTL-SHIFT-L
>
> CTL-SHIFT-B
>
> CTL-SHIFT-L
>
> CTL-SHIFT-L
> ```
>
> And you're done! Here's what happened:
>
> CTL-SHIFT-L runs LaTeX2e. Since the program is designed to work with
> BibTeX, and you have used the code in your TeX file, it generates a
> file called "example.aux" which contains all of the citations which
> you used in the document.
>
> CTL-SHIFT-B runs BibTeX. This searches for the ".aux" file, searches
> your BibTeX file for the relevant citations, and creates a file called
> "example.bbl". This file contains all needed information for the works
> you cited in the TeX file.
>
> Runs LaTeX2e again. With the bibliography file (example.bbl) in the
> directory, LaTeX can correctly create the bibliography inside the
> document.
>
> Runs LaTeX2e once more to make sure all of the references match up.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point this out in case anyone has the same problem. I had a hard time running bibtex with new (2022) mdpi's LateX template. After uninstalling and reinstalling everything, it worked properly for me putting in comments mdpi.bst's repeated function in line 250

```
FUNCTION {format.key}
{ empty$
    { key field.or.null }
    { "" }
  if$
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran to similar problems where my log file show this error when I try to load external bib file.

> ```
> INFO  texify.core - start process: miktex-bibtex.exe template
> FATAL texify.core - BibTeX failed for some reason.
> FATAL texify.core - Data: 
> FATAL texify.core - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\texify\mcd.cpp:1363
> FATAL texify - BibTeX failed for some reason.
> FATAL texify - Info: 
> FATAL texify - Source: Programs\MiKTeX\texify\mcd.cpp
> FATAL texify - Line: 1363
> ```

I just removed this code at line 250 from mdpi.bst

> ```
> FUNCTION {format.key} { empty$
> { key field.or.null }
> { "" }   if$ }
> ```

So then it worked